# Add Jquery to Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have the following code that I need to add to a template file that I'm working on in Wordpress. I am calling the jquery with    php wp_enqueue_script("jquery");  which is version 1.8.3. I've added the script in the header.php file and while I can get this working locally using dreamweaver, I can't figure out what's wrong when I try to run in it wordpress.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function (a, b) {
    var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
    var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
    return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
});
parent.append(items);
}

/* setup sort attributes */
$('#sLocation').data("sortKey", "span.wpcf-field-location-value");
$('#sSchool').data("sortKey", "span.wpcf-field-schools-value");


/* sort on button click */
$("button.btnSort").click(function () {
sortUsingNestedText($('#sortThis'), "div", $(this).data("sortKey"));
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sortThis">
<div class="fp-floorplans">
<div class="fp-link">
<a href="#">Community 1</a>
</div>
<div id="wpcf-field-location" class="wpcf-field-checkboxes wpcf-field-location"><span class="wpcf-field-name wpcf-field-checkboxes wpcf-field-location-name">Loation:</span>  <span class="wpcf-field-value wpcf-field-checkboxes-value wpcf-field-location-value">South</span>
</div>
<div id="wpcf-field-schools" class="wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-schools"><span class="wpcf-field-name wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-schools-name">School(s):</span>  <span class="wpcf-field-value wpcf-field-textfield-value wpcf-field-schools-value">Southwest</span>
</div>
<div id="wpcf-field-price-starting-at" class="wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-price-starting-at"><span class="wpcf-field-name wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-price-starting-at-name">Price Starting At:</span>  <span class="wpcf-field-value wpcf-field-textfield-value wpcf-field-price-starting-at-value">$100's</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fp-floorplans">
    <div class="fp-link">
<a href="#">Community 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="wpcf-field-location" class="wpcf-field-checkboxes wpcf-field-location"><span class="wpcf-field-name wpcf-field-checkboxes wpcf-field-location-name">Loation:</span>  <span class="wpcf-field-value wpcf-field-checkboxes-value wpcf-field-location-value">North</span>
    </div>
    <div id="wpcf-field-schools" class="wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-schools"><span class="wpcf-field-name wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-schools-name">School(s):</span>  <span class="wpcf-field-value wpcf-field-textfield-value wpcf-field-schools-value">Crowder</span>
    </div>
    <div id="wpcf-field-price-starting-at" class="wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-price-starting-at"><span class="wpcf-field-name wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-price-starting-at-name">Price Starting At:</span>  <span class="wpcf-field-value wpcf-field-textfield-value wpcf-field-price-starting-at-value">$100's</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fp-floorplans">
    <div class="fp-link">
<a href="#">Community 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="wpcf-field-location" class="wpcf-field-checkboxes wpcf-field-location"><span class="wpcf-field-name wpcf-field-checkboxes wpcf-field-location-name">Loation:</span>  <span class="wpcf-field-value wpcf-field-checkboxes-value wpcf-field-location-value">East</span>
    </div>
    <div id="wpcf-field-schools" class="wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-schools"><span class="wpcf-field-name wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-schools-name">School(s):</span>  <span class="wpcf-field-value wpcf-field-textfield-value wpcf-field-schools-value">Northeast</span>
    </div>
    <div id="wpcf-field-price-starting-at" class="wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-price-starting-at"><span class="wpcf-field-name wpcf-field-textfield wpcf-field-price-starting-at-name">Price Starting At:</span>  <span class="wpcf-field-value wpcf-field-textfield-value wpcf-field-price-starting-at-value">$100's</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<button id="sLocation" class="btnSort">Sort By Location</button>
<br />
<button id="sSchool" class="btnSort">Sort By School</button>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might be an idea to get Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug in Firefox to give you a little insight on whether you are getting any javascript errors during runtime.

Comment: any errors in the JS console? Can you confirm jQuery *is* loaded?

Comment: No errors in JS console and I'm using Firebug. jQuery is loading - <script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script> as seen in the view source code.

Comment: Maybe the problem is your use of the `load()` method on window.  This is deprecated in 1.8 http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: the <title> in your sample code is "jsfiddle". Don't suppose you have a jsfiddle link for us to play with?

Comment: @user1172854 is that the code your posting inside wordpress? i would check for php errors because your header.php doesnt look right

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark, but wrap all your code which uses `$` in

```
(function($){

    // your code here...

}(jQuery));
```

I think WordPress by default has jQuery in noConfilct mode or some such thing.

Comment: I just reloaded it and there is an error, but I'm not sure how to fix it: TypeError: $ is not a function
()/communities/ (line 25)
$(function(){

Comment: I changed $(funtion() { to jQuery(document).ready(function($) { and no longer get the error, but it's still not working.

Comment: So if there are no errors, and the output looks fine, then whats wrong?